# where to place redirection files after login in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, authentication

I am doing project in codeigniter. My login page is successfully executed. After login I want to redirect to home.php page. My login code is successfully executing only ,problem is there in redirection method.I have also provided my directory structure for reference.

code:

```
public function processlogin()
    {
   // $this->load->model('login_model');
   // $show =true;
   // $user = $this->login_model->showUser($show);
        $username = $this->input->post('user_name');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        {
            $this->load->model('login_model');
            $this->load->database();
            $query = $this->db->get_where('tbllogin', array('login_name' => $username,'password' => $password));
            $count1 = count($query->result());
            if($count1 === 1)
            {
                $this->load->helper('url');
                redirect('login_page/home');
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Error';
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Now please tell me where should I place my redirection files.

Comment: What happens when you login at the moment? What page do you end up at?

Comment: It displaying that page not found. This is my URL after login.     http://localhost:8004/index.php/login_page/home

Comment: It should be `application/controllers/login_page/<home controller>.php`, or `application/controllers/login_page.php` with method `home`. Where did your controllers folder go?

Comment: Your URL is correct. The Controller sounds the most likely candidate.

Comment: localhost:8004/index.php/login_page/home                             In above URL login_page is my folder and inside that folder home.php is my homepage after login.

Comment: @Yogeshk You can not have controller inside view folder, view is for viewing and controller is for controlling what is send to view. Please spend some time to study for example [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/codeigniter-from-scratch/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function processlogin()
    {
   // $this->load->model('login_model');
   // $show =true;
   // $user = $this->login_model->showUser($show);
        $username = $this->input->post('user_name');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        {
            $this->load->model('login_model');
            $this->load->database();
            $query = $this->db->get_where('tbllogin', array('login_name' => $username,'password' => $password));
            $count1 = count($query->result());
            if($count1 === 1)
            {
                $this->load->helper('url');
                $this->load->view('login_page/home');
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Error';
            }
        }
    }
```